# j2me service discovery and discoverable same time

Tags: java, java-me, mobile, client-server, bluetooth

I try to write a simple client/server application (all application is a bluetooth service and client). The client code find the bluetooth devices and register in to the local db. But when the inquiry running, it's not discoverable. (The server code run on another thread). I the emulator it's work (the scan time is 0), but when I installed into real phone (two SE and one nokia), the scan time is 10-15 sec. in this period the device undetectable by another devices.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're performing a Device Search, the Bluetooth radio will be busy in doing that and  thus it will not respond to other device's inquiry for discover.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I see you try to create simultaneously working server and client, right? Well, I think this is not gonna work, you have to make one phone server and the other one will be a client.

I would suggest looking through the example apps bundled with WTK or SE SDK, you may use them as reference. Also I would suggest reading [SE site for developers](http://developer.sonyericsson.com/community/java_me/java_me?tagSetID=1007&view=documents).